# unknown field 'ResolverModeReplica' in struct literal of type dbresolver.Config

Tags: go-gorm

I am trying to use the Database Resolver.  These [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/dbresolver.html) say that I can specify `ResolverModeReplica`.  But I get a build error when I do.

```
unknown field 'ResolverModeReplica' in struct literal of type dbresolver.Config
```

I looked at the source code for `dbresolver.Config` and, indeed, it doesn't seem to have that field.  The `dbresolver.Config` type does have a `TraceResolverMode` field, though.

```
type Config struct {
    Sources  []gorm.Dialector
    Replicas []gorm.Dialector
    Policy   Policy

    TraceResolverMode bool
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something?  Or are the doc out-of-date?